# Network - Routers conflicting in my subnet

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, wired-networking

I have a router whose IP is 192.168.1.1 and I be experiencing conflict with another router on my subnet (which probably has 192.168.1.1 as IP too).

I think when it tries to connect to the network, eventually taking the place of my router because when I try to access the config page of my router, which appears to me is a config page from another router that is not mine.

Do you have any solution except to change the IP of my router to an IP not common? As I have set up the exclusivity that only my IP router?

I work with dynamic IPs (wireless networking) and static (for wired). How do I?

I just want some setting in my router that affects all others, so that doesn't conflicts any more.

Comment: Why do you ahve two routers on the same subnet?  More info may help get an answer.

Comment: You cannot have routers with the same IP address. Changing one of them to something else is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but static ARP config on your device/host might help. You can specify the IP and MAC address of your router. This may not work if you have a bridge connecting your routers and hosts as it will do learning and filtering operation.

Another solution could be to configure your router and the related hosts on a different LAN(or VLAN) using a bridge. Probably, you can configure a trunk port on your router and the devices which need to access it. You can use RVI(IRB) to configure the L3 addresses. This should work as the packets relating to this router will become tagged and the other router will ignore it.

Not sure if this suits your requirement.